# SQL Server String Manipulation, splitting column value into 2 seperate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, data-manipulation

I'm using SQL Server 2014 ....

```
Select testvalue from testtable
```

returns

```
[000001][xXCEWkC+WDhe7EYo6feDmQ==]mnjQ3UkMjb1swK1wCTT75Q==
```

How can I split this value into 2 different values?

1. Value in 2nd brackets
2. Value after 2nd set of brackets

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SQL Server

```
select      right(testvalue,charindex(']',reverse(testvalue))-1)                                                            as col_1_option_a
           ,right(testvalue,len(testvalue)-patindex('%][^[]%',testvalue))                                                   as col_1_option_b
           ,right(left(testvalue,patindex('%][^[]%',testvalue)-1),patindex('%][^[]%',testvalue)-charindex(']',testvalue)-2) as col_2

from        testtable
;
```

#### MySQL

```
select  substring_index(substring_index(testvalue ,'[',-1),']',1)
       ,substring_index(testvalue ,']',-1)

from    testtable
;
```

Comment: Thank you but do you know how to accomplish this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can use **substring** and **locate**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(testvalue,
1,LOCATE("]",testvalue,LOCATE("]",testvalue)+1)) AS column1,
SUBSTR(testvalue,
LOCATE("]",testvalue,LOCATE("]",testvalue)+1)+1) AS column2 FROM testtable
```

Comment: Thank you but do you know how to accomplish this in SQL Server?